# Change password in root and error in accessing localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I tried to change password in my database but after i changed it right away, I got an error saying

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

and

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

How to fix this? Do i need to configure something about the connection and where can I fix it?

Comment: if you read the first message you are trying to connect without a password while you have set a password. that's where th error is coming from

Comment: How have you installed phpMyAdmin — is it part of some kit like XAMPP or WAMP? Have you configured an auth_type in the configuration file (a line line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` in `config.inc.php`?

Comment: I just reinstalled it but it erased all of the databases that were saved there

Answer (score 0):

Do you able to connect mysql in command line.

```
#mysql -u root -p
```

then provide the password to access mysql command line.

if Yes, then please make sure that you given the correct information while installing the phpmyadmin.

Comment: I just reinstalled it